# Why is using a lookup table slower than computing it in this case?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, benchmarking

I have two functions where the input `delta_E` can only be 3 possible values, 0, 4, 8. My first function directly computes it using numpy's exponential function.

```
def acceptance_prob(delta_E, beta):
    return np.exp(-delta_E*beta)
```

whereas my second function creates a dictionary, precomputing the 3 different values:

```
def acceptance_prob2(delta_E, beta):
    prob = {i: np.exp(-i*beta) for i in range(0,9,4)}
    return prob[delta_E]
```

Benchmarking both using magic command `%timeit` comes back with

```
%timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob(4,5)
3.02 µs ± 13.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob2(4,5)
10.9 µs ± 37.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Showing the precomputed method being just over more than 3 times slower than using `np.exp()`, which I don't get. To my knowledge computer languages usually use Taylor series expansion to compute exponential functions, so surely precomputing them and look them up instead of computing them every loop is quicker?

Comment: `acceptance_prob2` calculates three values, the other only does it once. If you *make* `prob` outside the function then the function should be faster.

Comment: So do I need to precompute it outside my function? Are you saying that each time I use `acceptance_prob2` it calculates 3 times? Am I not doing what my question says I am lol

Comment: `Are you saying that each time I use acceptance_prob2 it calculates 3 times? ` - **yes**.

Comment: If you are evaluating just one scalar value at a time, use `math.exp`.  `np.exp` should be used for array inputs - many values, for example `np.exp(-delta_E, np.arange(0,100))`.  This calculation will be a lot faster than repeated dictionary lookups.  The key to speed in `numpy` is to use the compiled numeric methods, not Python level iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def acceptance_prob(delta_E, beta):
    return np.exp(-delta_E*beta)

PRECOMPUTED_BETA = 5
PRECOMPUTED_PROB = {i: np.exp(-i*PRECOMPUTED_BETA) for i in range(0,9,4)}
def acceptance_prob2(delta_E, beta):
    if beta==PRECOMPUTED_BETA:
        return PRECOMPUTED_PROB[delta_E]
    return acceptance_prob(delta_E, beta)
```

Benchmarking both using magic command `%timeit` comes back with:

```
%timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob(4,5)
1.09 µs ± 9.66 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob2(4,5)
107 ns ± 0.322 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

But this is a more general solution:

```
In [15]: class Memoize:
    ...:     def __init__(self, f):
    ...:         self.f = f
    ...:         self.memo = {}
    ...:     def __call__(self, *args):
    ...:         if not args in self.memo:
    ...:             self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
    ...:         #Warning: You may wish to do a deepcopy here if returning objects
    ...:         return self.memo[args]
    ...:

In [16]: @Memoize
    ...: def acceptance_prob3(delta_E, beta):
    ...:     return np.exp(-delta_E*beta)
    ...:

In [17]: %timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob3(4,5)
245 ns ± 1.19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [18]:
```

Comment: I think your answer might be a bit of an overkill. Silly me didn't realise that I'm actually defining my dict everytime I run that function. Also just wondering what your class function is doing?

Comment: @user3613025 - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

Comment: Lazy evaluation and memoization is typically more effective than pre-computation.

Comment: @vy32 Would using either methods have any significant difference in speed at all in this case where there are only 3 precomputed values? This function is actually the acceptance probability for Ising model where it's looped over total number of lattices `N^2`, and then looped again over the number of equilibrium steps `EQ_STEPS`. I've fixed my problem my basically moving my precomputation out of these loops so that the values are really only being evaluated once this time. But I'm curious in if lazy evaluation and memoization would do any better in this case?

Comment: If you are only going to call the function with three possible values, and you are going to do it billions of times, you shouldn't even call a function. Just store them in an array, which is faster lookup than a dictionary. But why are you optimizing this so much in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are testing the time complexity in the way you think. The second function isn't just looking up the values. It is precomputing three values and then looking up one of them. If you precompute values before the function and then pass those to the function you would be testing the look up time more directly.

Something like:

```
def acceptance_prob2(delta_E, prob):
    return prob[delta_E]
```

```
prob = {i: np.exp(-i*beta) for i in range(0,9,4)}
%timeit -n 1000000 acceptance_prob2(4, prob)
```